# get json object by name from json array in android

Tags: android, json

I have json parse like this

Name

- brand
- value recom

  - value a
  - value b
- MPN
- value recom

  - value a
  - value b

I can show this value (brand and mpn) in list view . and I wanna if I click brand it will show value recom (value a and b) in list . and if I click mpn it will show value recom (value a and b) from name 2 in list too . any one can give me advice?? thanks

this my json parse

```
array (
    'features' => 
    array (
     'Recommendations' => 
      array (
        'id' => 
        'NameRecommendation' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'Name' => 'Brand',
            ),      
            'ValueRecommendation' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'Value' => 'Unbranded/Generic',
                ),

              1 => 
              array (
                'Value' => 'Canon',
                ),

              2 => 
              array (
                'Value' => 'Nikon',
                ),

              ),
  1 => 
          array (
            'Name' => 'MPN',
            ),
              'ValueRecommendation' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'Value' => 'mpn1',
                ),

              1 => 
              array (
                'Value' => 'aas',
                ),

              2 => 
              array (
                'Value' => 'aab',
                ),
```

Comment: use onItemclick() on listview and get the data related to that item and update where ever you want.

Comment: I know to use onItemClick , That i want ask how to get json data for this ?

Comment: You mean `{"Name":["a","b",{"recom":["a","b"]}]}` ?  Simply provide your json, please - the tree above can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

check this [url](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) 
and read the total data with `jsonobject` of -name

Answer (score 0):

You can read this in JSONArray object

Here is the example

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr); // this is you string as formatted in json array if not parse by this construct it will throw the jsonparseexception
```

now go through each object of this json by iterator

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++){
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.get(i).getJsonObject("value recom");
    String a = jsonObj.getString("a"); // here is your data for a object
    String b = jsonObj.getString("b"); // here is your data for b object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using google gson.

```
var getRowData =
[{
    "dayOfWeek": "Sun",
    "date": "11-Mar-2012",
    "los": "1",
    "specialEvent": "",
    "lrv": "0"
},
{
    "dayOfWeek": "Mon",
    "date": "",
    "los": "2",
    "specialEvent": "",
    "lrv": "0.16"
}];

    JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(request.getParameter("getRowData"));
     JsonArray  jsonArray = root.getAsJsonArray();
     JsonObject  jsonObject1 = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
     String dayOfWeek = jsonObject1.get("dayOfWeek").toString();
```

// when using jackson

```
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(getRowData);
          // advance stream to START_ARRAY first:
          jp.nextToken();
          // and then each time, advance to opening START_OBJECT
         while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            Map<String,Object> userData = mapper.readValue(jp, Map.class);
            userData.get("dayOfWeek");
            // process
           // after binding, stream points to closing END_OBJECT
        }
```